# Str replace for input to button

Tags: wordpress, search, str-replace

I am trying to change wordpress search submit `<input type="submit">` button to `<button>`. So i am trying to use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.str-replace.php). Here is my code:

```
add_filter('get_search_form', 'my_search_form_text');

function my_search_form_text($text) {
     $text = str_replace(
        '<input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">',
        '<button type="submit" class="search-submit btn btn-outline-primary"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>',
        $text
     );
     return $text;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme's folder `searchform.php` file is exists. If not copy from default theme to your theme.

Here replace your `<input>` with `<button>`